# Looking for an expression

Tags: word-request

[**Source**](http://www.mediaite.com/online/michelle-obama-clarifies-when-they-go-low-we-go-high-voting-is-our-high/)

I dont know what its called but I can give a brief description of what I am looking for. Go as low as to do something, condescend to something. I heard just "go low" recently is this it?

Comment: Without more detail, we can't understand exactly what you are asking. Please use the [edit] link to explain further. For instance, include a link to the source where you heard "go low".

Comment: ***To stoop to***: to do something that makes your moral standards lower *They have stooped to using threats of violence in order to get their way*. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stoop+to

Comment: @ChadThunder is [**this**](http://www.mediaite.com/online/michelle-obama-clarifies-when-they-go-low-we-go-high-voting-is-our-high/) the usage you mean?

Comment: Yes this is it what else could it mean?By it I mean what can be inferred from my description.

Comment: When you ask a question about something with an online source, you should always include a link in your question. This makes it much easier to understand exactly what you are asking about!